# Codeigniter Model loading improperly

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Here's the thing:
I loaded the model in the constructor method. Supposedly, I could use it on all the methods inside that controller, but I can only access it properly from the index method. When I used the loaded model in a different method - same controller, it gave me an error could not get function of non-object. I can use it on `index()` but why not on other methods inside the same controller? I loaded the same model on different controller and it works fine. I checked my controllers to see if there's any difference between the two and make sure that they're the same - in term of syntax and such, and they're the same.

Another is that I loaded another model, used it and worked fine, it inserts, create, etc but when I used the controller method to throw a `json_encoded` array back to the view because I used `$.ajax` on that, it gives me `responseText` - a string not a json - and it goes directly to error function of the `$.ajax`. I removed the model and the `$.ajax`triggered its success function.

I don't know where's the problem here. Also it happens to not just one model and comtrollers

Comment: if you load the model in your class constructor then it is available to all the methods in that class. for second question you need to post code and suggest you change your title to include ajax & json.

Comment: I know that when I loaded the model in the constructor, it would be accessible on all functions. Not this time. I don't know why it doesn't load the model properly

Comment: Post the code for both question.

Comment: for model not loading its probably a spelling or other issue. make sure your model file name, the class name, etc etc are all correct.

Comment: oh and DO NOT capitalize the first letter of the file name of your models. so like a pony model would be pony.php even though the class name is: class Pony extends CI_Model . and then when you refer to the model again its all lower case: $this->pony->gallop();